# Add vertical margin to anchors

Tags: html, css, mobile

**Motive**
Google receantly added a feature to display only mobile friendly pages in a mobile google search. Since I did already some CSS tricks to adopt mobile devices, I've confidently tried their test, but surprised by the results. Although I could quickly address 2 errors, there is one, that I have difficulty to quickly fix it: Links are too close together.
My site sports a menu like list, that altough I could quickly fix (and I may already have) and adopt to a mobile screen without any change in the desktop appearance, however sometimes links are inevitabely ends up above in each other in the body of each page. Also on one page there is a list that happens to have a list of links each other, but I'm not sure I would like to apply a CSS style to the list elements, to leave greater space in between list items (yet). I'm not seeking help on how to properly resolve that, (Like only leave gap between them, if they are actually end above each other) because it may fall under the "rethorical" question category. (Of course, I'm open to suggestions, if you have one.)

**Question**
I've decided, that I'll go with an ugly solution for now, that to leave a margin above&below each link regardless, what is surrounded with. Simply changing the margin did not worked. How can I do this? The page I'm currently testing is at http://adam.lehelj.com/ but the sub-domain is in currently only in hungarian.

**Edit**
The pages are generated from Markdown using [PHP Extra library by Michel Fortin](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) and I would prefer not to modify these files. It has a limited feature where to apply classes. (I believe it is for title, code and links.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer as to why you cannot set a margin top or bottom to an achor can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties), more specifically about the margin top and bottom:

> These properties have no effect on non-replaced inline elements.

one solution that you could use would be to set a `line-height` on your anchors.

Comment: display: inline-block; and you can apply margin

Answer (score 2):

With the links on the top left of your example page you can add a class to the anchor tags.

```
<a class="links" href=""></a>
```

The css could be something like..

```
.links {
    display: block; /* default is inline and top margin won't work on an inline element */
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
}
```

With the social links on the page bottom top margins should work fine for you as well. Just adjust the numbers until google is happy with the spacing and sure that people with fat fingers like me aren't clicking on 5 links at a time ;)

```
li {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
}
```

If the rest of your site is more complex add a class to the ul or li or wrapper div around them to differentiate styles as needed.

html

```
li class="social-links-item"
```

css

```
social-links-item {
    css here
}
```

html

```
<div class="social-links-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.social-links-wrapper li {
    css here
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I generate the pages from MarkDown files with the help of Michel Fortin's PHP Markdown Extra library, and have very limited options where to add classes. I'll add that to my question right away.